# Problems with graphics drivers on Latitude D600 running 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, unity, graphics, amd-graphics

this is my first time installing Ubuntu on a laptop, which is the Dell Latitude D600. I have been having a very specific issue related to what might be the graphics driver, but I am not completely sure.

The problem arises after the desktop environment loads up and everything appears to be working normally, but when I try to open any window, the window opens and closes in slow motion and the Ubuntu boot logo is all messed up/inverted colours. I have been searching forums far and wide for the fix and have tried several different solutions including switching to the GNOME classic desktop, installing fglrx for its 3D driver, and a weird solution involving using the boot flag video=LVDS-1:d.

Installing the classic desktop presents no improvement with the problem at all, fglrx appears to fix the problem with the boot logo, but after I log in to Unity or GNOME, the default background is displayed with no desktop environment loading at all, and it just stays like that, and finally, the boot flag option causes the screen to go black and stay black after boot.

It is easy to see how this problem is extremely frustrating, and if anyone here could provide me with any help at all it would be greatly appreciated, If you need any extra information about the laptop, all the hardware I believe is the factory hardware except a ram upgrade(2GB) and a 20GB hard drive. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I believe I have figured out the problem, I have a Radeon 9000 chip and unity runs very slowly on these chips and there is no real fix for it aside from installing Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: It's a fairly old system, although the extra ram should be of help. I suggest you try running a lighter display manager. Give [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) and [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) a try.

Answer (score 1):

Install the graphics drivr:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

If it already installed, then purge and reinstall

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-video-radeon && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```